# SharePoint 2013 Workflow Manager 1.0 Causes High CPU on Server

Tags: 2013, workflow, performance

I installed Workflow Manager 1.0 on my test SharePoint server following these links:

- [Installing Workflow Manager 1.0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193448.aspx)
- [Install and Configure Workflow for SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658588.aspx)
- [Blog on how to install SharePoint Workflow Manager](http://www.eblogin.com/eblogin/post/2013/04/18/SharePoint-2013-Workflow-manager-installation-on-single-server-Dev-Farm.aspx#.Uio0uTb4nmc)

I haven't setup any 2013 workflows yet but I am consistently seeing high CPU from these three services:

- 25%  Microsoft.Workflow.ServiceHost
- 10%  Microsoft.ServiceBus.Gateway
- 5%   Microsoft.ServiceBus.MessageBroker

Is this normal? Did I miss a setting?

I do not see why a vanilla install of Workflow 1.0 should be taking up 40% CPU at all times.

I have just started digging into all the logs on the server and will update with any info I find.

Comment: Does this occur when not configured with SharePoint? Just plain Workflow Manager?

Comment: Looking at my two farms I don't see the same CPU utilization on those services. Those are three components involved in workflow though. The ServiceHost is a Win32 service that talks connects to a Service Bus topic and listens for "jobs" to be broadcast to it. The other two are involved in the Service Bus piece. When an event happens in SharePoint (item added to a list), instead of SharePoint sending a message to each WF association, it sends one to a Service Bus topic which then sends N messages out based on how many subscriptions (aka: associations) there are on that list.

Comment: This is a good writeup on WorkFlow Manager farms: http://www.harbar.net/archive/2013/07/26/Article-Workflow-Manager-Farms-for-SharePoint-2013-Part-One-Core.aspx

Comment: @JohnChapman I have workflow configured with SharePoint

Comment: If I disable the 'Service Bus Gateway' or 'Service Bus Message Broker' service the CPU drops back down to normal.

Comment: I haven't had a lot of time to look into this but it looks like we may be uninstalling it from our SharePoint server and installing it on a separate box.  I will update with what happens when complete.

Comment: Hi Neil is there any update on your issue? We had the same thing happening on our server and we just force to stop those services as of the moment. :(

Comment: I'm having the same issue on my dev farm. It's really annoying. Any update on this?

Comment: We uninstalled from the Web front end and installed it on our app/search index server.  See my answer at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We uninstalled from our web front end server and installed it on our app server.

The app server hasn't shown the CPU issues that we saw on our web front end.

Some theories on why:

- Installed incorrectly the first time
- Workflow shouldn't be installed on a web front end
- The Windows server settings could have become different (although I am pretty sure both servers are identical)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some helpful tips on how to troubleshoot:
1. Make sure you have downloaded the correct version of SharePoint Designer 2013. You can download it via the following link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35491

2. Make sure you install and configure workflow for SharePoint Server 2013 correctly. You can refer to: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658588.aspx

3. Troubleshoot Workflow Manager 1.0 publishing, management and execution. You can refer to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193529.aspx

4. Use a powershell command to list workflows in the web application (IIS site) in question and then disable them. You can see http://sharepointjack.com/2013/sharepoint-server-wfe-high-cpu-caused-by-workflow/

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same high CPU problems on our Workflow Manager server. However, on our server we had already installed the February 2013 Cumulative Update.

The Workflow Manager event log was flooded with the following error message:

```
Failed SQL command after 1 tries with error '229'. Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'InsertTrackingAndStatus', database 'WFInstanceManagementDB', schema 'dbo'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.CompleteAsyncExecuteReader()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQueryInternal(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQuery(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Management.ExecuteNonQueryAsyncResult.OnEndExecuteSql(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Management.ExecuteSqlAsyncResult.EndAsyncResult(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.BackoffRetryAsyncResult.IsolateWithRetry(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.AsyncCompletionWrapperCallback(IAsyncResult result)
ClientConnectionId:d2d8661f-c63a-4e5c-98b8-aeac58348d53  Command Details:   SQL Text          : InsertTrackingAndStatus
  SQL Parameters    : 
    > @StatusRecords = Microsoft.Workflow.Management.SqlDataAccessProvider+InstanceStatusValuesCollection
    > @MetadataWithInstanceId = 
    > @Variables = Microsoft.Workflow.Management.SqlDataAccessProvider+VariablesCollection
    > @TrackingRecords = 
    > @StatusHistoryRecords = 
    > @DebugTraceRecords = 
    > @RollingStatusHistoryWindowSize = 1000
    > @RollingDebugTraceWindowSize = 5000
```

So it appeared to be a SQL permission issue. A quick internet search pointed me to the following MSDN discussion and a blog post that resulted from that:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/054d2a58-8847-4a6a-b1ab-05a79f49fe65/workflow-manager-cumulative-update-february-error
- http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.nl/2013/02/workflow-manager-cumulative-update-error.html

In that topic Microsoft presents an SQL script that fixes the database permissions. After I ran that script against our Workflow Manager databases the high CPU load and the error messages were gone.

Let's hope Microsoft releases an official fix for this.